# How to make a snapshot of the current view in in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, snapshot

I am using this function to take a snapshot for the current view

```
static UIImageView *screenShotOfView(UIView *view)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImageView *screenShot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenShot;
}
```

The snapshot doesn't work properly with the DatePicker. 
In the CALayer class reference : "Additionally, layers that use 3D transforms are not rendered [using renderInContext]"

is there a way around this?

thanks